# How to return tags containing one, two or three exact and specific words using get_tags

Tags: tags, regex

I'm using `get_tags` (outside the loop) with the argument `name__like` to return tags containing one, two or three **exact and specific words**.

I already tried (not working):

```
$args = get_tags( 'orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC', array('name__like' => 'group', 'name__like' => 'worker', 'name__like' => 'student' ) );
```

and I also tried to use `get_terms` (not working):

```
$args = get_terms( 'post_tag', array('name__like' => 'group', 'name__like' => 'worker', 'name__like' => 'student') );
```

It only seems to work when I try to get tags containing **only one word**, like this:

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC','name__like' => 'worker',);
```

I'm finding a bit lost... Is not possible to use an array here?

**This is the rest of my code, so far:**

```
$tags = get_tags($args ); 
    if ( !empty( $tags ) && !is_wp_error( $tags ) ): ?>
    <?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ): ?>
     <?php echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'" title="'.$tag->name.'" rel="tag">'.$tag->name.'</a>';?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: To clarify using your example, you want to find tags that have both of these words (or all 3)? Like "foo student bar worker" but not "foo student". `get_terms`/`get_tags` is no use for this and you'd have to write a custom query

Comment: @kero I want to find tags that have all of these 3 words

Comment: So a tag like `group worker student`, but _not_ `worker student`? *Or* tags like `big worker` but *not* `small person`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use multiple arguments of the same name. You've passed 3 `name__like` arguments. This isn't going to work the way you expect.

Arguments that support multiple possible values will accept an Array, but `name__like` is not one of those arguments. `name__like` can only be a String.

The value passed to name like is passed into the SQL like this in `WP_Term_Query::get_terms()`:

```
$this->sql_clauses['where']['name__like'] = $wpdb->prepare( "t.name LIKE %s", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $args['name__like'] ) . '%' );
```

So the value passed there is put directly into `t.name LIKE %(here)%`. But it's also excaped, so you *can't* use something like this (I tried):

```
'name__like' => 'worker% OR t.name LIKE %group'
```

The closest thing `WP_Term_Query` supports is multiple names:

```
'name' => ['worker', 'student', 'group']
```

But that will only match terms that are exactly worker, student or group.

To do what you're after will either require doing 3 separate calls to `get_tags()` or `get_terms()` with different values for `name__like`, *or* doing the query manually with `$wpdb`:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT
        t.*, tt.*
    FROM
        wp_terms AS t
    INNER JOIN
        wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON
            t.term_id = tt.term_id
    WHERE
        tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND 
        (
            t.name LIKE '%worker%' OR
            t.name LIKE '%group%' OR
            t.name LIKE '%student%'
        )
    ORDER BY
        t.name ASC"
);

if ( ! empty( $results ) ) {
    $tags = array_map( 'get_term', $results ); // Turn each result into a proper WP_Term object.

    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        echo $tag->name;
    }
}
```

Note that if those particular words are dynamic, you'll need to prepare the query with [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

Comment: Two things: 1- This is not exact because is also getting tags like "grouped", and 2- What do you mean by "...if those particular words are dynamic..."?

Comment: `name__like` would've had that issue to. You're going to need a custom query, but you'll probably need to use [regex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html). Is there a reason you're doing it this way? Maybe some sort of meta that's applied to tags would work better. Will certainly be easier to query.